# Get my JavaScript form to display two decimal places, including zeroes

Tags: function

I have read all the articles and could not get my form to display two decimal places, including zeroes, using the following;

```
function TwoDecimal(number){number=((Math.round(number*100))/100);
return number;
}

function compute()
{
```

var total= TwoDecimal(0);
if (document.price.Book.checked) total+=parseInt(document.price.Book.value);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `num.toFixed(2)` to show numbers upto two decimal places. Note: toFixed() returns in string format, so you have to convert that string to int using parseInt().

Use the below code.

```
function TwoDecimal(number){number=((Math.round(number*100))/100);
return number.toFixed(2);
}

function compute()
{
    var total = parseFloat(TwoDecimal(0));
    if (document.price.Book.checked) 
        total+=parseFloat(document.price.Book.value);
```

Comment: Thanks Utsav, that has solved a long standing annoyance.

Not sure why, but it was supposed to show $39.95, but it only shows $39.00, this was my other issue that I could never correct.

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Regards, Den.

Comment: Give me an example and your code. And let me know where exactly the problem is.

Comment: The price is set on the .html form page as follows;

<input name="Book" type="checkbox" id="Book" onClick="compute()" value="39.95" />
The code in the Java Script is the same as below (& above);

var total= TwoDecimal(0); if (document.price.Book.checked) total+=parseInt(document.price.Book.value);

Comment: I also have another field (Freight) at the bottom of the page that does not show the Two digit value;

US_Freight = price.US_Freight.value;
  if (price.Freight[0].checked)
  {
  price.US_Freight.value = 25.00
  }

Comment: Can you write your whole code in jsFiddle and give me that link?

Comment: Show me the output, add some html there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fpuakxs5/24/#&togetherjs=hadliDFT9E
Finally got it running, there are Two errors.
1) The Items don't add up correctly.
2) The US$ Freight won't show Two decimals.

Comment: See External Resources on the page.

Comment: Use parseFloat instead of parseInt..and let me know

Comment: That worked great, Just need to get the US$ Freight to do two decimals and things will be great.

Comment: For that use the twoDecimal() function. For eg.: price.US_Freight.value = TwoDecimal (25.00)

Comment: If you are satisfied don't forget to approve and upvote my answer.

Comment: Worked Perfect, you are a legend thanks ! Can't see where I can approve & Upvote.

Comment: I can't up-vote for your great work, as I need a rep of 15 or above, sorry.

Comment: Its ok, just remember to do that when you will get 15 rep :)